# Cannot declare custom property when using forwardRef in React

Tags: reactjs

I cannot declare custom property when using forwardRef in React; this works, `<MyInput ref={ref}></MyInput>`, but I cannot add a custom property to it like this:

`<MyInput someval={someval} ref={ref}></MyInput>`

error is

> "someval is not assignable to IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes"

```
//this is the parent component
export const Recognizer: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

  const ref = useRef(null);

  function handleClick() {
    ref.current.focus();
  }

  const [someval, setSomeVal] = useState(1);


return ( <div>
      <MyInput  someval={someval} ref={ref}></MyInput>
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>test</Button>)
};

// child component 

const MyInput = forwardRef(function MyInput(prop, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
      return {
        focus() {
          console.log("calling focus");
          inputRef.current.focus();
        },
        scrollIntoView() {
          console.log("calling scroll");
          inputRef.current.scrollIntoView();
        },
      };
    },
    []
  );

  return <div ref={inputRef} />;
});

export default MyInput;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using TypeScript, that error is from TypeScript Linter. To fix that problem, you need to define props type for `MyInput`, here is an example.

```
type MyInputProps = {
  someval: number
}
const MyInput = forwardRef<YourRefType, MyInputProps>(function MyInput(
  prop,
  ref
) {
  const inputRef = useRef(null)

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
      if (!inputRef.current) return

      return {
        focus() {
          console.log('calling focus')
          inputRef.current.focus()
        },
        scrollIntoView() {
          console.log('calling scroll')
          inputRef.current.scrollIntoView()
        },
      }
    },
    []
  )

  return <div ref={inputRef} />
})
```

You also need to define `YourRefType`.